# What is the best way to convert a series of boxes (right angles) from raster to vector?

Tags: vector, raster

Live trace distorts the straight lines that are crucial to my design.Its a complicated design to difficult to redraw. Please help me

Comment: Hi user46803, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? And please add some example images. Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

Can you trace them in Illustrator?  Drop some guides and snap to the for the right angles, or hold down shift when you are clicking with the pen tool to get the proper alignment...

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Illustrator, redraw them. Live Trace isn't perfect, and my experience using it has never yielded "great" results.

It has corner and angle settings but they're approximated.